# Issue when setting a Style for StackPanel elements in an ItemsControl

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-5.0

If I create a simple `StackPanel` and place some items in it and define a style to add margins, all works well, as demonstrated by this quick example:

```
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="module:ModuleElement">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20"/>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <module:ModuleElement/>
        <module:ModuleElement/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Obviously `module:ModuleElement` is my `UserControl`, but the issue remains if I use a default control, like a typical `Button`.

However, I don't want just a `StackPanel` - I want an `ItemsControl`. So I defined my control as such:

```
    <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" Margin="20,0,20,0">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <StackPanel.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="module:ModuleElement">
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,20,0,0"/>
                        </Style>
                    </StackPanel.Resources>
                </StackPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.Items>
            <module:ModuleElement/>
            <module:ModuleElement/>
        </ItemsControl.Items>
    </ItemsControl>
```

The few items added in the code above are for testing purposes - in this case the margins are default values (0).

What's going on? Why isn't this working? What do I need to do to fix this? I could of course set the margins manually for each element, but I feel I missing something and would much rather see it defined in a `Style`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might put the Style into the ItemsControl Resources instead of the StackPanel Resources:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" Margin="20,0,20,0">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="module:ModuleElement">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,20,0,0"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.Items>
        <module:ModuleElement/>
        <module:ModuleElement/>
    </ItemsControl.Items>
</ItemsControl>
```

Resource lookup in Silverlight traverses the "object tree" (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903952%28v=vs.95%29.aspx#referencing_resources_from_xaml)) which as far as I understand is not the visual tree, but the tree defined in XAML.

Comment: While this does work (and I will definitely up-vote) this doesn't really explain the issue. I've based my code on a similar scenario, where instead of a `StackPanel` I've used a `WrapPanel` and in that case my solution (placing the `Resource` in the `WrapPanel` definition) worked, so... why did it work then and not now?

Comment: You mean a WrapPanel as ItemsPanel in an ItemsControl? That would indeed be strange.

Comment: Yes, exactly. The code works in such a case. Unless I was lucky and the `WrapPanel` shouldn't have worked in the first place. ;P